# Why retrofit client crashes when there's no network connection?

Tags: java, android, crash, retrofit2, rx-java2

in my Android application I use Retrofit 2.2 and RxJava 2 for doing network calls. Everything is fine when the device is connected to a network. 
When i disable mobile and wifi network, the app crashes. 
The strange thing is that I can handle the error correctly but the app crashes anyway.

This is the API interface for Retrofit:

```
public interface BackendApi {

 @GET("v1/users/{uuid}")
 Observable<User> getUser(@Path("uuid") String userUuid);

}
```

The following method returns an Observable which will be subscribed in my view model.

```
@Override
public Observable<User> getUser(@NonNull final UUID id) {
    return api.getUser(id.toString()).map(user -> mapUser(user));
}
```

In the view model I subscribe to the Observable:

```
compositeDisposable.add(userService.getUser(userId)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(this::onGetUser, this::onGetUserError));
```

The following lines show the error handling method

```
 private void onGetUserError(final Throwable throwable) {
    log.error("onGetUserError, getting user failed because of {}", 
 throwable.getCause());
    if (isViewAttached()) {
        getView().showUserLoginOrRegisterError();
    }
 }
```

The problem is, when I disconnect the device from mobile and wifi connection, the onGetUserError() method get called correctly but anyway there's an unhandled exception crashing my app.

Here's the complete stacktrace:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/859ab3811a3ca5c63998a40b877c41bb

I have no idea how to get rid of these crashes!!

Regards
Martin

----------update 03.04.2017---------
there's another mysterium... 
On a Samsung Galaxy (S5), the stack trace is the same, but it is printed within my error-handler method! So I'm able to catch and handle the exception correctly.

```
 04-03 12:36:46.014 12078-12078/at.xxxx.yyyyapp 
 E/at.xxxx.yyyyapp.ui.startup.viewmodel.StartupViewModelImpl: 
 onGetUserError, getting user failed because of {}


 android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No 
 address associated with hostname)

 at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)

 at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)

 at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)

 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)

 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)

 at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)

at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelec
tor.java:170)

 at 
 okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:136)
```

On my other test devices (Nexus 5 and 6P) my error handler method is called but the app crashes anyway.

I have no idea how to solve this!

Comment: You need to handle exception thrown by interceptor. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697459/handle-exceptions-thrown-by-a-custom-okhttp-interceptor-in-kotlin-coroutines/65469952#65469952

Answer (score 1):

i had the exact same problem and just solved.

i hadn't implemented onError handling when a response received and that was the cause.

```
someObservable
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<Response>() {
      @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        disposables.add(d);
      }

      @Override public void onNext(Response response) {

      }

      @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
        // implement this!!!
      }

      @Override public void onComplete() {

      }
    });
```

hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue where retrofit would crash if the server is down or there is no network connectivity.
I had to add `addCallAdapterFactory` to the retrofit client. There are a lot of tutorials available on how to add a custom call adapter factory.

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(NetworkResponseAdapterFactory())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
```

Comment: NetworkResponseAdapterFactory?

Comment: @David You can follow this article https://medium.com/@mariusz.soltysiak/error-handling-in-retrofit-using-networkresponseadapter-library-e60c24f330c4