# Handle exceptions thrown by a custom okhttp Interceptor in Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, exception, okhttp, interceptor, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using a custom `Interceptor` along with Retrofit client in my Android app, that throws an Exception under some specific circumstances. I'm trying to make it work using Kotlin coroutines.

The problem is that I'm unable to handle the before mentioned error, since in the moment the exception is thrown from within the Interceptor instance, it crashes the whole app instead of being caught in the coroutine's `try/catch` statement. While I was using the Rx implementation, the exception was flawlessly propagated to the `onError` callback where I was able to handle it the way I needed.

I guess this is somehow related to the underlying threads that are being used for the network call, please see the logs below from the place where the call is made, from the interceptor just before throwing the exception, and the stacktrace:

```
2019-11-04 17:17:34.515 29549-29729/com.app W/TAG: Running thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
2019-11-04 17:17:45.911 29549-29834/com.app W/TAG: Interceptor thread: OkHttp https://some.endpoint.com/...

2019-11-04 17:17:45.917 29549-29834/com.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.app, PID: 29549
    com.app.IllegalStateException: Passed refresh token can\'t be used for refreshing the token.
        at com.app.net.AuthInterceptor.intercept(AuthInterceptor.kt:33)
```

What am I supposed to do in order to be able to catch and handle this exception from the Interceptor correctly? Am I missing something?

Comment: "I guess this is somehow related to the underlying threads that are being used for the network call" -- are you saying that in the Rx implementation, both what you have as "Running thread" and "Interceptor thread" were the same? You might want to edit your question and provide a [mcve], showing the interceptor code and the full stack trace of your unhandled custom exception.

Comment: Only `IOException` is propagated to the caller. All other exceptions are delegated to the uncaught exception handler. This means that instead of throwing an `IllegalStateException`, you should throw an `IOException` instead.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You should subclass `IOException` and use that to send information from your interceptors to your calling code.

We consider other exceptions like `IllegalStateException` to be application crashes and do not send them over thread boundaries because we don’t want to burden most callers with catching them.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest solution of the issue. I only wonder why in the Rx implementation any of the exceptions was forwarded to the caller anyways. Is is something internal within Retrofit's Rx Adapter?

Comment: TBH I find that a really bad design decision. Why do you think you could decide for the user whether or not they want to 'bear the burden' of catching more generic exception? Why my custom exceptions are forced to be IOException even if semantically they are not?

Comment: @fyodor here's a discussion of this design decision: https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/5457

Comment: @JesseWilson since when? this made me waste half day! Why? makes no sense to me. IOException = network issue. I use that exception to decide when to retry automatically when the network comes back online. I've created an issue about it https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3505

Answer (score 45):

You may catch the exception in your custom `Interceptor` and return an empty response with some specific `message` and `code`. I have implemented a custom `Interceptor` to handle the situation like when you do not have or slow internet connection etc... Actually coroutine's suspend functions throws exception when dealing with network calls. In my experience, you can follow 2 approaches. **1.** wrap your all network call in `try...catch` or **2.** create a custom `Interceptor` and handle exceptions there and return some specific response.

**Approach 1:**

```
try {
    webservice.login(username, password)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    //...
}
```

**Approach 2:**

Create a custom `Interceptor` and handle exception there.

```
class LoggingInterceptor : Interceptor {

   @Throws(Exception::class)
   override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
      val request = chain.request()
      try {
          val response = chain.proceed(request)
        
          val bodyString = response.body()!!.string()

          return response.newBuilder()
            .body(ResponseBody.create(response.body()?.contentType(), bodyString))
            .build()
      } catch (e: Exception) {
          e.printStackTrace()
          var msg = ""
          when (e) {
             is SocketTimeoutException -> {
                msg = "Timeout - Please check your internet connection"
             }
             is UnknownHostException -> {
                msg = "Unable to make a connection. Please check your internet"
             }
             is ConnectionShutdownException -> {
                msg = "Connection shutdown. Please check your internet"
             }
             is IOException -> {
                msg = "Server is unreachable, please try again later."
             }
             is IllegalStateException -> {
                msg = "${e.message}"
             }
             else -> {
                msg = "${e.message}"
             }
          }

          return Response.Builder()
                .request(request)
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                .code(999)
                .message(msg)
                .body("{${e}}".toResponseBody(null))
      }
   }
}
```

I have created gist for complete implementation of `LoggingInterceptor` with print logs of request and response. [LoggingInterceptor](https://gist.github.com/amirraza/28e46b3aa4305cd32ac2d3b56fe5f523)

Comment: Thanks for your ```Approach 2```. It is so helpful!

Comment: Oh man, the best approach on the whole internet.

Comment: Oh, man! you saved my ocean of time, just no word for your solution Approach 2 is working like hell. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where SSLHandshakeException was thrown inside interceptor and never propagated to the call origin.
The following code fixed the behavior in custom interceptor:

```
            try {
                chain.proceed(request)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                throw e
            }
```

Now every error that I receive from network stack is propagated to the place where call was made.
Sorry if this is obvious or something, but for me it was quite shocking that chain.proceed(request) does not throw the IOException further. And in order to do so, you need to rethrow it manually.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know what exactly you need, but understood like this:

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()  
        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request();
                okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);

                // todo deal with the issues the way you need to
                if (response.code() == SomeCode) {
                   //do something
                    return response;
                }

                return response;
            }
        })
        .build();

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()  
        .baseUrl(url)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```