# Catch Block is not Catching Retrofit exception

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, retrofit, okhttp

I am using retrofit interceptor to check internet connection, if internet is not available I am throwing NoConectivityException.

Problem is that **Interceptor is throwing exception but catch block is unable to get it.**

**Logs I am getting after app crash:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: com.msm.ProjectApp, PID: 9571
**java.lang.Error: com.msm.ProjectApp.Network.NoConnectivityException: No Internet Connection**
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
 Caused by: com.msm.ProjectApp.Network.NoConnectivityException: No Internet Connection
    at com.msm.ProjectApp.Network.AuthInterceptor.intercept(AuthInterceptor.kt:18)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:212)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:172)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

**Custom Exception class is below**

```
    class NoConnectivityException : IOException() {
    override val message: String
        get() = "No Internet Connection"
}
```

**Auth interceptor is below:**

```
class AuthInterceptor(var authToken: String) : Interceptor {

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

    if (!isNetworkAvailable(AppClass.context)) {
        Log.d("InterceptorTag", "intercept: no internet")
        throw NoConnectivityException()
    }

    Log.d("InterceptorTag", "intercept: yes internet")

    val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder() //getting new request
    newRequest.addHeader("Authorization", authToken)

    return chain.proceed(newRequest.build())
}

private fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val nw = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw) ?: return false
        return when {
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            //for other device how are able to connect with Ethernet
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
            //for check internet over Bluetooth
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    } else {
        return connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected ?: false
    }
}
```

}

**Calling retrofit api below**

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                val categoriesResponse = sharedViewmodel.memeApi.getCategories()
                adapterCategories.setCategories(categoriesResponse.body()!!.data.categories)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    adapterCategories.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) { //I have tried catch(e:NoConectivityException) also
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    showToast(e.message!!)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, your Exception is descended from `java.io.IOException` and not some other class of your own that's also named IOException, right? Because of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697459/handle-exceptions-thrown-by-a-custom-okhttp-interceptor-in-kotlin-coroutines

Comment: Could you provide your implementation of `getCategories()`?

Comment: @broot     @GET("/categories")
    suspend fun getCategories(): Response<CategoriesResponse>

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have tried extending Exception class also.

Comment: Yes, it definitely won't work if you do not extend java.io.IOException.